# ksh break and continue based on values

Tags: shell, ksh

I amrunning below script in KSH shell. I want to run the loop for 6 times to call Java program and in betwen if there is no
exception found , then it should return =0. if in all the 6 iteration, we found any exception then it should return 3.

```
integer max=7;i=1

while [[ $i -lt $max ]]
do
    Java call statement;
    error_cnt=`$processing_file | grep -i excption | wc -l `
    if (( $error_cnt == 0 ))
    then
        return_code=0;
        break
    else
       Continue with java call 
    fi 
    (( i = i + 1 ))
done
```

If in all the 6 iterations still we finds exceptions then it should return 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to define `$processing_file`. Also, you can just `grep` that file directly

Then, you're breaking out of your loop if there a no errors, when you want to break out if there *are* errors.  Then, after your loop breaks or finishes, you want to actually return with the `$return_code`.

```
integer max=7;i=1
integer return_code=0

while [[ $i -lt $max ]]
do
    Java call statement;
    error_cnt=`grep -i exception $processing_file | wc -l`
    if (( $error_cnt != 0 ))
    then
        return_code=3;
        break
    # you don't need an else here, since continuing is the default
    fi
    (( i = i + 1 ))
done
# return with the code you specify
return $return_code
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But how the loop will return code 0 in case there is no exception in the processing file.

Comment: @John - we're defining the 0 up at the top, in `integer return_code=0`.  If no errors change that, then that 0 will fall all the way to the bottom of the script and be returned.